# Prevent inheriting operator new and delete

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

(I did scan, but couldn't find anything similiar, if dupe please close).

Is there a way to prevent these two operators from being inherited? For example:

```
struct foo{
  static void* operator new(std::size_t) { 
    // special
  }
  static void operator delete(void* p, std::size_t) { 
    // special
  }
};    

struct bar : public foo {
};
```

Now `bar` will inherit the two operators - in this trivial case, not such a big deal, problem arises if there are data members in `foo` and `bar` (and worse in my case, as allocation for `foo` needs to be done differently to `bar`!) Now the way to avoid this is that in `bar`, I would implement the operators too. However if there are lots of derived types, the likelyhood of forgetting to override somewhere is quite possible. So question is, is there a way to prevent these operators from being inherited?

NOTE: c++03 (and willing to accept some compiler specific solution if it's specific to gcc)

Comment: @delnan, if that was an option, I would not be asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define an intermediate foo which calls global new/delete again and derive from that.

```
class foo_without_new : public foo
{
protected: 
 foo_without_new(){} // only derived types should be able to construct foo_without_new!
public:    
 void *operator new(size_t sz) 
 { 
     return ::operator new(sz);
 }
 void operator delete(void*p) 
 { 
     return ::operator delete(p);
 }
}; 

class Bar : public FooWithoutNew
{
};
```

There is some more work involved if you have to forward constructors of course.

Comment: +1 - nice idea, we already have an intermediate derivation which will be perfect for this...

Answer (score 3):

Scott Meyers has a nice answer for that situation: Add a size check!

```
struct Foo
{
  static void * operator new(std::size_t n)
  {
    if (n != sizeof(Foo))  // subsumes check for n == 0
    {
      return ::operator new(n);
    }
    // your code here
  }
}
```

You can customize the behaviour to taste, e.g. abort if there's a wrong size, etc. This way, you have a default solution for any derived class you may not know about but still have your own operator kick in only for the base class itself.

Beware that the above code *may* not behave as expected if any of the classes in the hierarchy are empty.

Comment: What happens if `bar` doesn't have any data members ? i.e. `n = sizeof(Foo)`

Comment: hmm... it's probably safer to rely on implementing the operators in `bar`, and make that part of the "process"... I fear there is no technical solution to this...

Comment: @iammilind: Yeah, empty classes may not be detected by this. It depends on what the application is, though. If you want a fixed-size pool allocator, then this would still be useful. If you have stricter requirements, then indeed you need more work...

Comment: @Kerrek, yeah it's stricter - as in it's a typed pool allocator, so delete would not work correctly! :(

Comment: @Nim: Hmm... if you want, perhaps you could post the entire design as a new question? Maybe the pool allocator can be implemented without overloading member-new?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Why do you need to check for n == 0? I thought operator new was well defined in that situation.

Comment: @john: It's *your* responsibility to ensure that your operator behaves correctly when size 0 is passed. Indeed, the default operator new also meets this guarantee, but here we're writing our own operator. Without the check, the "your code here" part would otherwise have to pay attention to this special case.

Comment: @Kerrek, I don't think it's a failing in the allocator design, but just a combination of how we're using it (as in not changing the way we construct) and this resolution(inheritance) business with operators new and delete! :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what about declaring them as *private* methods?

Comment: erm, the only way to construct would then be via public static methods, which is not ideal...

Answer (score 1):

Operators new and delete [are not member functions](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/010.htm) -- they are static -- and they cannot be inherited or blocked from inheritence.

The reason it *looks* like inheritence is that overload resolution preferes `Base::operator new` in the following snippet because it is more specific than the global operator.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int x;
    void * operator new (unsigned int s) {
        std :: cout << "Base\n";
        return :: operator new (s);
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

int main () {
    new Base ();
    new Derived ();
}

// Prints "Base\nBase\n"
```

To prevent this, you must

- provide another, more-specific overload, or
- don't use `operator new`.

I know that's not brilliantly helpful but it's the only way. Other "solutions" are hackey and pervert the meaning if the operator -- see the linked GOTW for just how easily this can go wrong.

Comment: fine, so *inheriting* is the wrong expression, how does one prevent this resolution?

Comment: Only by further overloading. Once a Derived is-a Base you can't make it cease to be so in any particular circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the principle of inheritance. `bar` inherits `foo`'s behaviour.
Would it be satisfactory to overload these operator again in `bar`?

```
struct foo{
    static void* operator new(size_t) { 
       // special
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p, size_t) { 
       // special
    }
};    

struct bar : public foo {
    static void* operator new(size_t s) { 
       return ::operator new (s);
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p, size_t s) { 
       ::operator delete (p);
    }
};
```

I have tried and it works fine. The only problem could be there:

```
bar * pbar = new bar(); // this is ok
foo * phaha = pbar;
delete phaha;           // this is not (foo:operator delete(void*, size_t) is called)
```

Comment: I am aware of this, my question is is there a way to avoid having to define the redirect to standard operators in `bar`?

Comment: I see, but I don't think so. But @Kerrek SB 's answer is great as it may avoid having to take care of this (I did't try).

Answer (score 0):

> problem arises if there are data members in foo and bar

I think that this fear is misplaced. Because `new/delete` are `static` functions; so even if you have data members, they will not affect in anyway. Let the operators get inherited normally. Also, there is no way you can stop inheriting them.

**Edit**: From your comment, I learn that you have genuine case where you may want to somehow stop `new` and `delete` being propogated. One work around is below.

```
  struct foo;
  template<typename T>
  T* New { return ::operator new T; }
  template<>
  foo* New<foo> { return new foo; }

  struct foo{
  template<class T> friend T* New();
  private:
  static void* operator new(size_t) { 
     // special
  }
};
```

Above is a pseudo code. The idea is to make a wrapper like `New` and use it as `New<foo>()` or `New<bar>()`; So always proper version of `new` will be called. Same for `delete`.

Comment: on the contrary, `foo` is allocated from an object pool, if `bar` has members, then there is an issue..

Comment: If the slots in your object pool differs in size from what's being passed in the size argument you can assert or throw an exception

Comment: @iammilind, unfortunately I don't have the luxury of making such major changes (as in instead of `new foo`, `new bar`, changing the code base to do `New<foo>` and `New<bar>`), if I did, I'd use some factory...